# Smtp not able to receive/send mail

Tags: java, email, netbeans, smtp, gmail

It was working a few days ago but I don't know why it's not working now. Actually, we are working on visual cryptography on NetBeans, this is supposed to mail share images to the user for authentication. I even deleted the entire project and open it again from my zip file but still not working mail part. I'm not getting any error either, also checked the login details.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;  
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;  
  
public class MailUtil {  
  
    private String SMTP_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com";  
    private String FROM_ADDRESS ="project4u@gmail.com";  
    private String PASSWORD = "1234567";  
    private String FROM_NAME = "Mail from TEES:";  
  
    public boolean sendMail(String[] recipients, String[] bccRecipients, String subject, String message) {  
        try {  
            Properties props = new Properties(); 
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST);  
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.debug", "false");  
            props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");  
  
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new SocialAuth());  
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);  
  
            InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress(FROM_ADDRESS, FROM_NAME);  
            msg.setFrom(from);  
  
            InternetAddress[] toAddresses = new InternetAddress[recipients.length];  
            for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {  
                toAddresses[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);  
            }  
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);  
  
  
            InternetAddress[] bccAddresses = new InternetAddress[bccRecipients.length];  
            for (int j = 0; j < bccRecipients.length; j++) {  
                bccAddresses[j] = new InternetAddress(bccRecipients[j]);  
            }  
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, bccAddresses);  
  
            msg.setSubject(subject);  
            msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");  
            Transport.send(msg);  
            return true;  
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {  
            Logger.getLogger(MailUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
            return false;  
  
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {  
            Logger.getLogger(MailUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
            return false;  
        }  
    }  
  
    class SocialAuth extends Authenticator {  
  
        @Override  
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
  
            return new PasswordAuthentication(FROM_ADDRESS, PASSWORD);  
  
        }  
    }  
}
```

This is GlassFish server 4.1 log
I am not sure how to copy here, I am sorry if this is wrong

Severe:   javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials q128sm1693476pfb.67 - gsmtp
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:893)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:814)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:728)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at visual.EmbeddedImageEmailUtil.send(EmbeddedImageEmailUtil.java:104)
at visual.AddImageDt.image(AddImageDt.java:70)
at visual.AddImageDt.processRequest(AddImageDt.java:190)
at visual.AddImageDt.doGet(AddImageDt.java:214)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

'''
Thank you

Comment: Did you check they page they linked to you to explain the error? https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?p=BadCredentials&visit_id=637564995861290116-2326799055&rd=2#cantsignin

Comment: Yes I checked but didn't work

Comment: What didnt work exactly did you try creating the app password that fixes the issue 99% of the time.